# Подгружать информацию из другой страницы

Tags: javascript

Каким способом можно выгрузить какую-либо информацию с другой страницы?

**Для примера** возьмем сайт www.vk.com, нужно к примеру, чтобы на основной страничке в углу экрана отображалось название первой аудиозаписи. Т.е., нужно, чтобы скрипт подключался к `http://vk.com/audios` и уже оттуда брал какую-то информацию на основную страницу. Надеюсь, объяснил понятно.

Answer (score 1):

`Ajax` запрос - это то, что Вам надо.

Если на Вашем сайте используется какой-либо javascript framework (типа jQuery, Prototype, Angular и т.п.), то в них есть методы, которые помогут Вам воспользоваться `ajax`.

Кратко и очень поверхностно: `ajax` фактически, это вызов какой-либо другой страницы вашего или другого сайта. Этот вызов запускает некий код и возвращает обратно данные. Главное преимущество - все это буделается без перезагразки страницы.

Применительно к Вашему примеру

1. используя `ajax` вызываете некий скрипт, расположенный на Вашем сайте (PHP или другой язык).
2. Этот скрипт делает всю основную работу: подключается к `http://vk.com/audios` и уже оттуда берет какую-то информацию. В конце скрипт возвращает HTML, который Вы хотите отобразить на странице-источнике
3. полученный HTML код вставляется в область в углу экрана

Думаю, что в общих чертах приницп работы `ajax` должен быть более понятен теперь...

Самое главное преимущество - нет перезагрузки страницы.

`ajax` может возвращать все, что угодно... JSON-объект, serialized дата, готовый HTML... Но это уже дла каждого задания свое...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?